# Periodic solution of different equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying the following exercise :
Let $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^2, \mathbb{R}^2)$ and $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^2$ $f(kx)=k^2f(x)$ for $k\in\mathbb{R}$

Show that any periodic solution of $y'=f(y)$ is constant.

Thank you in advance